# Comparing today's date with date field in sqlite database table

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, sqlite

Can I compare a **date** of **text** datatype stored in my database table with today's date that I found using python datetime?
I imported sqlite and datetime in python.

**Screenshot of my python code.**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0Uxr.jpg

Comment: Do not post a screenshot of your code, put it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parameter substitution`.

**Ex:**

```
c.execute("select name from table where date =?", (x,)
```

**[MoreInfo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)**